# How can I properly define a height for rows in my Vaadin Flow Grid in Vaadin 24?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

This approach below worked fine until Vaadin 23.
From Vaadin 24 on, it still basically works, but not if you first set a larger amout of items as input, an then a smaller one. The resulting problem is that the grid's tbody tag recieves a wrong height property, so that the user can scroll further than rows are available.

Any suggestions?

TestView.java

```
@Route(value = "test")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/components/test.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")
public class TestView extends Div {


    public TestView() {
        Button button1 = new Button("Put 10 items to grid");
        Button button2 = new Button("Put 2 item to grid");

        Grid<String> grid = new Grid<>();

        grid.addClassName("my-grid");
        grid.addColumn(s -> s)
                .setWidth("200px")
                .setHeader("Value");
        grid.setHeight("100px");

        button1.addClickListener(e -> addItems(grid, 10));
        button2.addClickListener(e -> addItems(grid, 2));

        add(new VerticalLayout(new HorizontalLayout(button1, button2), grid));

        setSizeFull();
    }

    private void addItems(Grid<String> grid, int max) {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            items.add("Item " + i);
        }
        grid.setItems(items);
        grid.setItems(
                query -> {
                    Stream<String> stream = items.stream();
                    if (query.getInMemorySorting() != null) {
                        stream = stream.sorted(query.getInMemorySorting());
                    }
                    return stream.skip(query.getOffset()).limit(query.getLimit());
                },
                query -> items.size());
    }
}
```

test.css

```
:host(.my-grid) {
  --lumo-size-m: 20px;
  --lumo-size-xl: 24px;
}

:host(.my-grid) [part~='row'] {
    max-height: var(--lumo-size-m);
    height: var(--lumo-size-m);
}

:host(.my-grid) [part~='row'][aria-rowindex="1"] {
    max-height: var(--lumo-size-xl);
    height: var(--lumo-size-xl);
}
```

[WrongScrollbar Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmS3Z.png)

Comment: Please checkout https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/styling

Comment: sorry did not help either. But this lead me to the idea to apply my size constraints on the cells insted of the rows - this works in vaadin 24.

Comment: Not sure why it worked in V23 and not V24, but in any case the aria-rowindex attribute was never intended as a CSS target. If you are using it to target the header row, there are much more reliable part names available for that, on the page linked to by Simon. And yes, setting height on rows has never been particularly reliable, even in earlier versions – cells are much better for that.